# Find Trace and Norm for $K(\alpha)/K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Let the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ over $K$ be $X^d+c_{d-1}X^{d-1}+…+c_1X+c_0$.
Prove that: $$Tr_{K(\alpha)/K}(\alpha)=-c_{d-1}, N_{K(\alpha)/K}(\alpha)=(-1)^dc_0$$

I found this question on an online document while learning trace and norm by myself. It contains a proof for a more general result with a lot of theorems and settings that I'm not familiar with. Is there an easy way to prove just this special case with basic knowledge about Galois extension?

Comment: What's your definition of trace/norm?

Comment: Given $x∈K(\alpha)$, $G=Gal(K(\alpha)/K)$. Trace is the sum of $ϕ(x)$ among all $ϕ∈G$ , and Norm is the product of $ϕ(x)$ among all $ϕ∈G$.

Comment: In general, $K(\alpha)/K$ is not Galois, and so you want to replace the group $G$ with the set of all $K$-algebra homomorphisms of $K(\alpha)$ into a fixed algebraic closure of $K$.  If you do this, your definition coincides with the usual one for $\alpha$ *separable* over $K$.  In the inseparable case, your definition needs to be modified slightly.

Comment: Assuming $\alpha$ separable over $K$, i.e. the minimal polynomial has distinct roots, you can solve your problem by showing that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ factors as $$\prod\limits_{\phi \in \operatorname{Hom}_{K-\textrm{alg}}(K(\alpha),\overline{K})} (x - \phi(\alpha))$$ and multiplying everything out.

Answer (score 1):

Take the $K$-vector space basis $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dotsc, \alpha^{d-1}$ of $K(\alpha)$.

Multiplication by $\alpha$ in $K(\alpha)$ is represented by matrix
    \begin{equation*}
    \vec{A} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0      & 0      & 0      & \dots  & 0      & -c_0     \\
        1      & 0      & 0      & \dots  & 0      & -c_1     \\
        0      & 1      & 0      & \dots  & 0      & -c_2     \\
        0      & 0      & 1      & \dots  & 0      & -c_3     \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots   \\
        0      & 0      & 0      & \dots  & 1      & -c_{d-1}
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
a $d \times d$ matrix whose characteristic polynomial is $f_\alpha(t)$.

From the characteristic polynomial, we can read off the trace and norm, giving the required result.

Comment: Well, I haven't thought about extension field in matrices before, but I'll try to understand the relation.

Comment: It's slightly simpler than you think, I expect. $K(\alpha)$ is just a vector space over $K$, and the trace of $\alpha$ is the trace of the linear map given by multiplication by $\alpha$ in $K(\alpha)$ - so it can be written as a matrix.

Comment: Ah, I just saw your definition of trace in the comments above - I was assuming a different one. I'll leave the answer anyway.

Comment: See related question containing this one as well as the answer given by @B. Mehta   https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2757516/300700