# How to find minimal polynomial in $GF(2^3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I have $GF(2^3)$ field defined by $\Pi(x)=x^3+x+1$. From literature they say those are the minimal polynomial, but I can't understand the operative method to find them. Any explanation for a general method?

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\textbf{Elem.} & \textbf{Polyn.} & \color{red}{\textbf{Minimal Polyn.}} \\
0 & 0 & \color{red}{x} \\
\alpha^0 & 1 & \color{red}{x+1} \\
\alpha^1 & \alpha & \color{red}{x^3+x+1} \\
\alpha^2 & \alpha^2 & \color{red}{x^3+x+1} \\
\alpha^3 & \alpha+1 & \color{red}{x^3+x^2+1} \\
\alpha^4 & \alpha^2+\alpha & \color{red}{x^3+x+1} \\
\alpha^5 & \alpha^2+\alpha+1 & \color{red}{x^3 + x^2 + 1} \\
\alpha^6 & \alpha^2+1 & \color{red}{x^3 + x^2 + 1} \\
\end{array}$$

Note: I saw another post about minimal polynomial but there was no such method explained

Comment: For the field of eight elements you can use the fact that $\alpha,\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^4$ are Galois conjugates and hence share a minimal polynomial. The same applies to $\alpha^3,(\alpha^3)^2=\alpha^6$ and $(\alpha^6)^2=\alpha^5$. As $\alpha^6$ is the reciprocal of $\alpha$, the respective minimal polynomials are each others reciprocals as well. Note that $\alpha^5=1/\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^3=1/\alpha^4$ so the reciprocal relation holds for the entire class of conjugates.

Comment: For a method of sorts ... there are several. I outlined one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2234211/11619). A possibly simpler one is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3048104/11619), but that works only when the element of interest generates the extension field.

Comment: Maybe I miss something, I can't obtain from your example the linear system (cit):

"

At this point we can set up a linear system for the unknowns $c_0,c_1,\cdots,c_5$ and find a solution of the system
$$
c_0+c_1\beta+c_2\beta^2+c_3\beta^3+c_4\beta^4+c_5\beta^5=0
$$
by plugging in the values of the powers $\beta^i$ and then set the coefficients of all the powers of $\alpha$ to zero (the powers $1,\alpha,\cdots,\alpha^4$ are linearly independent (because $4<m=5$) so this is valid."

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I understand now. Thank you so much for you great link!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements of $GF(8)$ are exactly the roots of the polynomial $X^8-X\in GF(2)[X]$. This polynomial decomposes into irreducible polynomials as follows,
$$X^8-X = X(X+1)(X^3+X+1)(X^3+X^2+1).$$
If the field $GF(8)$ is given as $GF(2)[X]/\langle X^3+X+1\rangle$ and $\alpha$ is a zero of $X^3+X+1$, then (as stated above), $\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^4$ are the zeros of $X^3+X+1$ and $\alpha^3,(\alpha^3)^2=\alpha^6,((\alpha^3)^2)^2=\alpha^5$ are the zeros of $X^3+X^2+1$.

Comment: So, knowing the irriducible polynomial over $GF(8)$, I simply try plugging the $\alpha^i$ into one or another and the one who is the zero is it's minimal polynomial?

Comment: Indeed, that's correct

Comment: And to find the irriducible polynomial over a given field, one must show that $p(0)=p(1)\equiv 1 \pmod p$ and that the polynomial has an odd number of factor, right? Because I think this is the tricky part of finding minimal polynomial